# Bootstrap DateTimePicker not showing calendar when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

recently I tried to use `Bootstrap DateTimePicker` in my `ASP.NET MVC` project, and the calendar just wont show up. I believe I already put the Scripts and CSS in the right order.

Here is my CSS and Scripts :

```
 <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And this is my View Page :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Tanggal Survey </label>                          
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>                      
               </div>
              </div>
           </div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD MMMM YYYY'
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

And when I click the input, **it just show the date and never show the pop-up calendar**, 
[here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaUeT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the examples here: [minimum setup](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup)

For your datepicked to open with clicking on the input you need to remove the glyph and go with the minimum setup.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

  $('.datetimepicker-addon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev('input.datetimepicker').data('DateTimePicker').toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thankyou for answering. I tried your answer but the pop-up calendar still won't show up and just showing the date in the input box

Comment: Can you share your output from your browser console? Is there any kind of error there?

Comment: I didn't use the  $(this).prev('input.datetimepicker').data('DateTimePicker').toggle();
tho, if I use it, there's an error refering to the toggle() code

Comment: Are you by any chance using this in a partial view? https://forums.asp.net/t/2044951.aspx?MVC+Javascript+not+working+in+partial+view

Comment: I believe I'm not using any partial view. It's just a standart 'Create' view using a Html BeginForm in it.